# Integral equal to Riemann Zeta Function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, riemann-zeta

As part of a homework problem in Rudin, I need calculate

$$ \int_{1}^{N} \frac{[x]}{x^{s+1}} \,dx$$ where $[x]$ is the floor function. Clearly $[x]$ has derivative $0$ everywhere but the integers.

Is the following correct?:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{N} \frac{[x]}{x^{s+1}} \,dx &= \Big( -\frac{[x]}{s}x^{-s} \Big)_{1}^{N} + \int_{1}^{N} \frac{d}{dx}([x])\frac{1}{x^{s+1}} \,dx \\
&= \Big( -\frac{[x]}{s}x^{-s} \Big)_{1}^{N} + \int_{1}^{2} \frac{d}{dx}([x])\frac{1}{x^{s+1}} \,dx + \cdots + \int_{N-1}^{N} \frac{d}{dx}([x])\frac{1}{x^{s+1}} \,dx \\
&= \Big( -\frac{[x]}{s}x^{-s} \Big)_{1}^{N} + 0 \\
&=\frac{-1}{s} \Big(\frac{N}{x^{-s}} -1 \Big)
\end{align}$$

Is this a correct calculation? If not, please do not explicitly give the correct answer, rather a hint as to where I've gone wrong would be nice.

Comment: When using align (instead of eqnarray), **do not** put ampersands on both sides of the =. It will turn your $\rm\LaTeX$ into a mess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not apply integration by parts here because one of the [function is not continue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Product_of_two_functions), as **Hint** the right way is to write your intgral as:
$$\int_{1}^{N} \frac{[x]}{x^{s+1}} \,dx=\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\int_{i}^{i+1} \frac{[x]}{x^{s+1}}  $$

now what is the value of $[x]$ in the interval $[i,i+1]$ and continue your calculations.

Comment: I had an idea of needing to split the integral up, and the Integration by Parts was my first thought...forgot about hypotheses

Comment: I think $x$ in this case should be $i$. But it is just an intuition. Could you help to give a more rigorous explanation? I have struggled with this for some time.

Comment: First let's in the start forget about the function and write $f(x)=\frac{[x]}{x^{s+1}}$ Can you see why  $\int_{1}^{N} f(x) \,dx =\int_{1}^{2} f(x) \,dx+\int_{2}^{N} f(x)\,dx$? use additivity of integration. This can be generalized to : $\int_{1}^{N} f(x) \,dx =\int_{1}^{2} f(x) \,dx+\int_{2}^{3} f(x) \,dx+\int_{3}^{N} f(x)\,dx$ and finally what I wrote in my answer : $$\int_{1}^{N} f(x) \,dx =\int_{1}^{2} f(x) \,dx+\int_{2}^{3} f(x) \,dx+\cdots+\int_{N-1}^{N} f(x)\,dx$$ Now : HOw do you continue from here ? by computing the integral $\int_{i}^{i+1} \frac{[x]}{x^{s+1}}=....$ and sum for each i

Comment: Of course as a strat you should replace $[x]$ by $i$ because inside the interval $[i,i+1]$ we always have $[x]=i$ hence , $\int_{i}^{i+1} \frac{[x]}{x^{s+1}}= \int_{i}^{i+1} \frac{i}{x^{s+1}}=i\int_{i}^{i+1} \frac{1}{x^{s+1}}=.....$ Now when you finish the computation you will get $\int_{i}^{i+1} \frac{[x]}{x^{s+1}}= S(i)$ for some function $S$ and you can conclude that : $$ \int_{1}^{N} \frac{[x]}{x^{s+1}} \,dx=\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} S(i)=S(1)+S(2)+\cdots+S(N-1) $$ and you can try to simplify this sum and then you are done

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is incorrect. Under the framework of Riemann integral,
one can not integrate by part an integrand which has jump discontinuities.

If you really want to use integrate by part, you can interpret the integral
as a [Riemann–Stieltjes integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral). One has

$$\int_1^N \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^{s+1}} dx
= \int_{1^-}^{N^+} \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^{s+1}} dx
= -\frac1s\int_{1^-}^{N^+} \lfloor x \rfloor d\frac{1}{x^s}\\
= -\frac1s\left( \left[\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^s}\right]_{1^-}^{N^+} -
\int_{1^-}^{N^+} \frac{1}{x^s} d\lfloor x \rfloor
\right)\tag{*1}
$$
Notice $\lfloor N^+ \rfloor = N$ and $\lfloor 1^- \rfloor = 0$, we have
$$\left[\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^s}\right]_{1^-}^{N^+}
= \frac{1}{N^{s-1}}$$

For the integral in last expression of $(*1)$, notice $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is constant over intervals of
the form $(k,k+1), k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and has a jump discontinuity $1$ at $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, i.e

$$\lfloor k^+ \rfloor - \lfloor k^- \rfloor =
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \left(\lfloor k+\epsilon \rfloor - \lfloor k-\epsilon \rfloor \right) = k - (k-1) = 1$$
The integral in last expression of $(*1)$ reduces to a sum:
$$\int_{1^-}^{N+} \frac{1}{x^s} d\lfloor x \rfloor =
\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k^s}$$
Combine these, we have

$$\int_1^N \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^{s+1}} dx = 
\frac1s \left( \sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{k^s} - \frac{1}{N^{s-1}}\right)$$

The same answer you will get if you continue to treat the integral as Riemann integral but split it as a sum of integrals over intervals of the form $(k,k+1)$, $1 \le k < N$.

Answer (score -1):

We have
\begin{align}
\int_1^N \dfrac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^{s+1}}dx & = \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \int_k^{k+1} \dfrac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^{s+1}}dx = \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}k \int_k^{k+1} \dfrac{dx}{x^{s+1}} = \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\dfrac{k}s \left(\dfrac1{k^s} - \dfrac1{(k+1)^s}\right)\\
& = \dfrac1s \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\left(\dfrac1{k^{s-1}} - \dfrac{k}{(k+1)^s}\right) = \dfrac1s \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\left(\dfrac1{k^{s-1}} - \dfrac{k+1}{(k+1)^s} + \dfrac1{(k+1)^s}\right)\\
& = \dfrac1s \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\left(\dfrac1{k^{s-1}} - \dfrac1{(k+1)^{s-1}} + \dfrac1{(k+1)^s}\right) = \dfrac1s\left(1-\dfrac1{N^{s-1}} + \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \dfrac1{(k+1)^s}\right)\\
& = \dfrac1s\left(\sum_{k=1}^N \dfrac1{k^s} - \dfrac1{N^{s-1}}\right)
\end{align}